# Rails 3: User has_many association id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models in my Rails 3 app:

**User**

model:

```
has_many :videos, :dependent => :destroy
```

controller:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
  redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end
```

**Video**

model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :surveys, :dependent => :destroy
```

controller:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
  redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end

  def show
    @video = Video.find(params[:id])
    @original_video = @video.panda_video
    @h264_encoding = @original_video.encodings["h264"]
    @surveys = Survey.all
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**Survey**

model:

```
belongs_to :video
```

controller:

```
 before_filter :signed_in_user

def signed_in_user
  unless signed_in?
    store_location
  redirect_to signin_path, notice: "Please sign in."
  end
end

  def show
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @survey }
    end
  end
```

So in my app, a User has many Videos, and each Video has many Surveys (a.k.a. Reviews). Think of how Rotten Tomatoes works. A user has be signed in to either access a video, or write a review. Any review that user submits, while signed in, is automatically associated with that user...and this is what I'm trying to figure out with my app.

How do I associate the user id with the review? Right now, when a user is signed in, his name is automatically associated with all the reviews, whether he wrote them or not.

Comment: just added my controller info

Answer (score 2):

You want to use your Video class as a join model via the `through` option:

```
User
  has_many :surveys, :through => :videos

Survey
  has_one :user, :through => :video
```

This should let you do:

```
@user.surveys
@survey.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason this isn't as simple as:

```
User
  has_many :surveys

Survey
  belongs_to :user
```

If so, more info/code is required for a useful answer.

Comment: I just added some of my controller info above...the surveys only exists if the video exists. The video belongs to the user, and the survey belongs to the video.

Comment: Thanks. Given the extra info, I agree with jdeseno's answer - use has_many :through.